# Replacing File if Exist in a Directory using C#

Tags: c#, file-upload

I want to upload a file in C# Gui and check if it exists already in that particular folder. But why is it that only the 2nd file is replaced not even if the first file exists already? I do have 2 upload button.

The two buttons.

```
    private void upload_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog file = new OpenFileDialog();
        file.Title = "Browse the File";
        file.Filter = "PDF Files (*.PDF)|*.PDF|" + "Images (*.BMP;*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|" +
        "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string file_path = Path.GetDirectoryName(file.FileName.ToString());
            string file_obj = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName.ToString());
            string file_itself = file_path + "\\" + file_obj;
            upload_label1.Text = file_itself;

        }
    }

    private void upload_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog file1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        file1.Title = "Browse the File";
        file1.Filter = "PDF Files (*.PDF)|*.PDF|" + "Images (*.BMP;*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|" +
        "All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (file1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string file_path1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(file1.FileName.ToString());
            string file_obj1 = Path.GetFileName(file1.FileName.ToString());
            string file_itself1 = file_path1 + "\\" + file_obj1;
            upload_label2.Text = file_itself1;

        }
    }
```

Update button

```
    private void update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            string ext = upload_label1.Text;
            ext = ext.Substring(ext.Length - 3, 3);
            if (File.Exists(@"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "." + ext))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("exists");
                File.Delete(@"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "." + ext);
                File.Copy(upload_label1.Text, @"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "." + ext, true);
            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(upload_label1.Text, @"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "." + ext, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eeee)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eeee + "");
        }
        try
        {
            string ext1 = upload_label2.Text;
            ext1 = ext1.Substring(ext1.Length - 3, 3);
            if (File.Exists(@"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "_part2." + ext1))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("exists2");
                File.Delete(@"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "." + ext1);
                File.Copy(upload_label2.Text, @"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "_part2." + ext1, true);
            }
            else
            {
                File.Copy(upload_label2.Text, @"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "_part2." + ext1, true);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception eeee1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(eeee1 + "");
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Updated!");
        }
```

.

Comment: The whole purpose of object oriented programming is the ability to write code once and reuse it

Comment: Sorry. But I'm still new to C# and I don't have any idea on how oop works. That is why I you can find redundant codes here. Sorry again.

Comment: @user3569641: is file extension of both files same or different?

Comment: it can be the same or different..

Comment: Would you consider create a new variable to store the file path so that you don't need to use two same sets of code?

Comment: @user3569641 Since you're new to C# and could use some guidance/feedback, may I suggest posting code snippets such as this to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for some peer input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any issues in the two Upload Button events, however in your Update Button there is a bug in the second try/catch block:

```
File.Delete(@"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "." + ext1);
```

In the first block, you build the same string in four places:

```
@"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "." + ext1
```

In the second block, you build this string in three places, but miss the fourth:

```
@"uploads\\" + civil_case.Text + "\\" + civil_case.Text + "_part2." + ext1
```

So, your second try/catch is deleting the file from the first one, so only the second file remains at the end. Does this match what you're observing?

Also, since you mentioned a lack of C#/OOP experience, here is a slightly better way to break out the Upload Buttom code (as an example):

```
/// <summary>
/// Show a File Dialog and update a label if the dialog returns a file name.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="label">The label to update.</param>
private void ShowFileDialogAndUpdateLabel(Label label)
{
    var file = new OpenFileDialog
    {
        Title = "Browse the File",
        Filter = "PDF Files (*.PDF)|*.PDF|Images (*.BMP;*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPEG;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|All files (*.*)|*.*"
    };

    if (file.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        label.Text = Path.GetFullPath(file.FileName);
}

private void upload_1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowFileDialogAndUpdateLabel(upload_label1);
}

private void upload_2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowFileDialogAndUpdateLabel(upload_label2);
}
```